# How to get server's ssl certificate in a human readable form?

Tags: ssl, certificates

For example, I want to find out when the certificate for encrypted.google.com expires (i.e. `Not After` date), and what other domains may use it for authentication (Subject Alternative Names).

Comment: I don't think we need the x509 tag. In 30k+ Q's this the 1st time it's come up, I think for the level of this Q the use of ssl and certificates is plenty. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: These are all the Q's that contain x509: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=x509

Comment: On the off chance I asked this Q on meta: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/do-we-need-a-x509-tag

Comment: Looking at answers below, apparently the x509 certificates had little to none to do with the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply write it:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect encrypted.google.com:443 < /dev/null \
   2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

Other options than `-enddate` can be used to retrieve other fields. `-text` outputs most of the information.

See also `keytool` from java:

```
keytool -printcert -sslserver encrypted.google.com:443
```

It will print the whole certificate chain if possible (some of the certificate possibly retrieved from the Java certificate store).

Comment: what about Subject Alternative Names?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, `openssl x509` only displays it with `-text`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I saw no other method in wiki either beyond `-text`. http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName. I think what Stephane's provided is your answer.

Comment: @slm, note that J.F.Sebastian answered his own question, he was just sharing his nice script to retrieve certificate information in a useful way. I was just mentioning an alternative way to call the `openssl` command. (generally, you don't need `-in` as `openssl` takes its input from stdin, and you can retrieve (some) individual parameters without having to parse the output of `-text`).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I hadn't given the other answer a thorough look, since it looked like an awful lot of code, now looking at it I see what you're saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To print server's certificate as text using openssl:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Show server's certificate in a human-readable form.
#
# Usage: $ show-cert HOST [PORT]
#
exec <&- # close stdin to suppress `read:errno=0` from openssl
exec openssl x509 -noout -text \
     -in <(openssl s_client -connect "$1":"${2:-443}" -showcerts)
```

Or using Python to get output in json format:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Show server's certificate as json.

Usage:
  $ %(prog)s HOST [PORT]
"""
import json
import socket
import ssl
import sys

def getcert(addr, timeout=None):
    """Retrieve server's certificate at the specified address (host, port)."""
    # it is similar to ssl.get_server_certificate() but it returns a dict
    # and it verifies ssl unconditionally, assuming create_default_context does
    with socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=timeout) as sock:
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=addr[0]) as sslsock:
            return sslsock.getpeercert()

def main(argv):
    host = argv[1]
    port = int(argv[2]) if len(argv) > 2 else 443
    print(json.dumps(getcert((host, port)), indent=2, sort_keys=True))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Example:

```
$ getcert encrypted.google.com | jq -r '.notAfter, .subjectAltName[][1]'
Mar 20 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*.google.com
*.android.com
*.appengine.google.com
*.cloud.google.com
...
```

The latest version: [`getcert.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/7901011)